# GRAILS --- How to pass a String literal in g:link to controller method

Tags: grails

How to pass a String literal value in g:link (from a view, .gsp) to a controller method?

Comment: lol, why the downvotes? it's far from obvious for a newbie and serious time was spent trying to figure this out, and this question might save someone's else time

Answer (score -3):

```
<g:link controller="simpleExcel" action="downloadSampleExcel"
    params="[s: 'RAF']">Download Sample Excel</g:link>
```

--- if you have a SimpleExcelController with a downloadSampleExcel(String s) method. Mind the single quote, as it deceived me greatly.